# Copy First Column to New Column (Renamed Header) at End in CSV with Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, csv, terminal

I have a bunch of csv files where I need to:
1) Create a new column at the end with a new header "External Id"
2) I need to copy data from the first column in the CSV to this newly created column

As opposed to opening up each csv file to do this manually, are there any terminal scripts or commands for mac os that can make this easier?

Thanks!
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html) (`brew update && brew install miller`).

Starting from

```
fielda,fieldb
3,a
5,d
```

and running

```
mlr --csv put -S '$newField=$fielda' input.txt
```

You have

```
fielda,fieldb,newField
3,a,3
5,d,5
```

If you want to do it for a lot of CSVs (make a copy of your CSVs first, so you have a backup), put these in a new folder, open the shell in this folder and run

```
mlr -I --csv put -S '$newField=$fielda' ./*.csv
```

All your CSVs will have the new field inside.

Comment: You my friend have saved me countless hours of work. This worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch for the help!